# Do Machine Learning Algorithms read data top-down or bottom up?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, random-forest

I'm new to Machine Learning and I'm a bit confused about how data is being read for the training/testing  process. Assuming my data works with date and I want the model to read the later dates first before getting to the newer dates, the data is saved in the form of earliest date on `line 1` and `line n` has the oldest date. I'm assuming that naturally data is being read from `line 1` down to `line n`, but I just need to be sure about it. And is there any way to make the model(E.g Logistic Regression) read data whichever direction I want it to?

Comment: Well, the data are read from the data file line by line, 1, 2, 3, etc., but they might be processed in that order, or in a random order, or all at once (so order isn't an issue at all).  When you set up the training process, you have some control over that. This is an interesting question, but it's suitable for datascience.stackexchange.com instead of SO.

Comment: Thanks, next time I'll ask over there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A machine learning model in supervised learning method learns from all samples in no order, it is encouraged to shuffle the samples during training.

Most of the times, the model won't get fed with all samples at once; the training set is split into batches, batches of random samples or just in whatever order it is in the training set.